# What's the catch in Ford Mondeo Econetic driving at 3 liters per 100 kilometers story?

Tags: fuel-consumption

News report ([here](http://www.norwaynews.com/en/~view.php?72O64542R4483at285Oni844OI2882SG76EHi253LbN8) and [here](http://www.barentsobserver.com/murmansk-oslo-uddevalla-on-one-tank-of-diesel.4963973.html) and lots more [can be found](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=murmansk+oslo+ford+mondeo) that two guys drove Ford Mondeo Econetic with 1,6 liters diesel engine and got fuel consumption of about 3 liters per 100 kilometers.

That's incredible - they drove at about 65 kilometers per hour and that's not a traffic jam where hybrid cars show themselves well, so "hybrid" alone doesn't explain how it was possible.

For comparison: I know an owner of a Ford Focus C-Max with 2 liters gazoline engine and they report fuel consumption of about 14 liters per 100 kilometers. I agree that comparing gas versus diesel is not completely fair, but still 3 liters versus 14 liters looks impressive.

This story is widely discussed and some people say the car was "tuned".

I wonder what tuning that might be? How is 100 kilometers on 3 liters of fuel on a 1,6 liters car possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its a combination of things:

the 1.6 engine is a common rail diesel turbo with a particulate filter, not sure if that makes a difference in itself.

tyres on eco models tend to be skinnier and of a harder compound meaning they cause less rolling resistance.

Eco models normally also have drag reducing features - such as filled in wheel trims and reduced apertures for the radiator/grilles at the front and streamlined mirrors etc.

removing all extra weight will also help - how full was the tank? half full will reduce the weight significantly.

In my diesel car, 65km/h is just barely idling in fourth gear (fifth causes it to labour a bit) I havent looked at my consumption at that speed but I know at 120km/h I average around 4.2 litres per 100km.